# Integration tests with dependencies on response cookies throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to find a way to write an integration test for a component which that is dependent on HttpContext and uses cookies.

My problem is an Exception is thrown when it tries to write anything to the response cookies.

Here's some code to reproduce the problem.

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web;
using Moq;

namespace CookieTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CookieTest
    {
        private Mock<HttpContextBase> _httpContextMock;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequest(null, "http://localhost/", "");
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
            var response = new HttpResponse(sw);
            _httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

            _httpContextMock.Setup(t => t.Request).Returns(new HttpRequestWrapper(request));
            _httpContextMock.Setup(t => t.Response).Returns(new HttpResponseWrapper(response));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCookieWrite()
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextMock.Object;
            var expectedValue = "value";
            var cookies = httpContext.Response.Cookies;
            var cookieToAdd = new HttpCookie("key", expectedValue);

            // to illustrate that these are not null
            Assert.IsNotNull(cookies);
            Assert.IsNotNull(cookieToAdd);

            // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            // at System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(HttpCookie cookie)
            // at CookieTest.CookieTest.TestCookieWrite() in CookieTest.cs: line 41
            cookies.Add(cookieToAdd); 

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, httpContext.Response.Cookies.Get("key"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?  Seems odd, as the [`Add` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpCookieCollection.cs,169) doesn't look like it should throw a NRE by itself...

Comment: Hi @JamesThorpe, yes, that is the full stack trace. I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: I've also had a look at the .NET source and can't seem to find where it's going wrong

Comment: I've just replicated it - my stack trace has `System.Web.HttpResponse.OnCookieAdd(HttpCookie cookie)` at the top, above the `Add` method.

Comment: Looks like it's chaining to the [Request's cookies](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,2079).

Comment: I should add, I only see the `OnCookieAdd` part of the stack trace when I'm debugging - I don't see it if I run the test normally.

Comment: Seems that there's an [internal constructor for `HttpResponse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,153) that allows specifying the `HttpContext`, which is [required for getting hold of the corresponding `HttpRequest`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,139) in order for [`OnCookieAdd` to add it to the request cookies too](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,2079).  Only because the `Request` property returns null, because you can't construct it with an `HttpContext`, it fails.  Seems that these objects...

Comment: ...are _really_ intertwined.  Unsure at this point what the best course of action for you is...

Comment: Sounds like too much refactoring involved to get one test working - I really hope there's a workaround somewhere

Comment: It's definitely a weird problem. If you catch and throw away the NPE, the cookie has been added, so it's some weird framework thing. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response contains a private field called `_context` which requires a reference to both itself and the request,  if you set the field like so:

```
var response = new HttpResponse(sw);
response.GetType()
        .GetField("_context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .SetValue(response, new HttpContext(request, response));
_httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
```

Then the `NullReferenceException` will no longer be thrown. Additionally, the test was failing as you compare the `HttpCookie` object with a string, you need to edit the assertion to check against the `Value` property like so:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, httpContext.Response.Cookies.Get("key").Value);
```